# Trouble reading (and comparing) pixels in SDL2

Tags: sdl, pixel

I'm loading a PNG file in SDL2 and I'm trying to find 'special' pixel colours to track during a spritesheet animation. I've put these pixels into my image but my code isn't finding them.

I'm using this code to read the pixels (taken from internet, wrapped into my own Texture class):

```
Uint32 getpixel(SDL_Surface *surface, int x, int y)
{
int bpp = surface->format->BytesPerPixel;
/* Here p is the address to the pixel we want to retrieve */
Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x * bpp;

switch(bpp) {
case 1:
    return *p;
    break;

case 2:
    return *(Uint16 *)p;
    break;

case 3:
    if(SDL_BYTEORDER == SDL_BIG_ENDIAN)
        return p[0] << 16 | p[1] << 8 | p[2];
    else
        return p[0] | p[1] << 8 | p[2] << 16;
    break;

case 4:
    return *(Uint32 *)p;
    break;

default:
    return 0;       /* shouldn't happen, but avoids warnings */
}
}
```

And these are the important bits of code I'm using to compare pixels to the 'special' values I've set before:

```
        // convert special SDL_Color to Uint32
        Uint32 spec1 = SDL_MapRGBA(_texture->GetSDLSurface()->format, _spec1.r, _spec1.g, _spec1.b, 255);
        Uint32 spec2 = SDL_MapRGBA(_texture->GetSDLSurface()->format, _spec2.r, _spec2.g, _spec2.b, 255);
```

...and, while looping through all pixels in each sprite frame...

```
                    // get pixel at (x, y)
                    Uint32 pix = _texture->GetPixel(x, y);

                    // if pixel is a special value, store it in animation
                    if (pix == spec1)
                    {
                        SDL_Point pt = {x, y};
                        anim->Special1.push_back(pt);
                        found1 = true;
                    }
                    else if (pix == spec2)
                    {
                        SDL_Point pt = {x, y};
                        anim->Special2.push_back(pt);
                        found2 = true;
                    }
```

Now, I'm setting a breakpoint in these if-statements to check if the colour has been found, but the breakpoint is never reached. Does anyone know what the problem is?

P.S. I've tried also using SDL_MapRGB() but that doesn't work either.

[edit]

Okay so I tried putting a pixel at 0,0 of the whole image with RGB values 66, 77 and 88. It read them in as 84, 96 and 107, so obviously the colours are either being changed or not read in properly. However, when I try it with a specific alpha value, it reads it in perfectly. I would change my system to only use alpha values but it seems the pixel editor I'm using removes the alpha value once you put in the pixel and blends it in with the rest of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Your formula to offset is not correct, it should be :

```
Uint8 *p = (Uint8 *)surface->pixels + y * surface->pitch + x
```

(`x` does not need to be multiplied by `bpp`)

From the [docs](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface)

*pitch
The length of a surface scanline in bytes*

The pitch, also called stride is computed as following :

```
pitch = width * bytes per pixel

bytes per pixel = (bits per pixel + 7) / 8
```

When you are at correct byte offset, get an `Uint32` (for a 32bpp image) from it and do your comparison.